# Sending a transaction to a cluster with 3 peers

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to extend my existing single orderer, single peer hyperledger fabric system to 2 orders and 3 peers. I've managed to add a new order so that the system works even if one of the orderers is down.

Now I'm trying to do the same with peers but I'm having difficulties to save a new record on the blockchain, when one of the peers is down.

On saving, I'm using Java SDK to send transaction proposal to all three peers - I receive 2 successful and one failing `ProposalResponse` - I'm filtering out the failed on and send the collection of successful ones to `org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel#sendTransaction(java.util.Collection<org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.ProposalResponse>)`.

The method returns `CompletableFuture<TransactionEvent>` which I'm subscribing to with `whenComplete`. I've noticed that when one of the peers is down the `future` doesn't complete unless the offline peer becomes available again.

Is it how the system is designed? I'd expect fabric and SDK complete a task even if only one peer is available and then let peers update themselves when they become online. Is there some way to achieve a behaviour like that?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I've realized that I'm using `sendTransaction` with default transaction options that add all peers as event peers so the transaction cannot be finished unless all of them receive the event.

Comment: What is the chaincode endorsement policy? Does it need endorsement from all 3 peers?

Comment: @adnan.c Tbh I just started working with fabric and completely forgot to look into it - I believe we have some basic policy taken based probably from some tutorial. As 3 peers are there for resilience I'd assume that it shouldn't really need all 3 peers for endorsement - just one would be enough. Is there a way to configure it this way?
Right now I have two approaches - passing `NOfEvents.createNoEvents()` to ` sendTransaction(Collection<ProposalResponse>,TransactionOptions)` or using all successful peers returned with `sendTransactionProposal` as endorsing peers. Does it make sense?